Generating a table such that every pair of integers (a,b) exists at least in a row

Suppose I want to generate a table that has $50$ rows and $6$ columns. Each entry in that table can be an integer from $1$ to $75$ inclusive. Can I do it such that every pair of integers $(a,b)$ ($1 \leq a \leq 75$, $1 \leq b \leq 75$ and $a \neq b$) is at present in at least one of the $50$ rows, i.e, $a$ and $b$ must be present in the same row, and if not, can it be shown why?

Can this also be generalized to any table having $m$ rows and $n$ columns, having integer entries from $1$ to $p$ inclusive?
I have tried a naive attempt of trying to pair every number individually, i.e, I will pair $1$ with every number first.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\ \hline
1 &  12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
I however quickly saw that things got out of hand at the number 2, managing which pairs were already formed and which were yet to form was almost impossible.

The general problem of constructing a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns with the numbers $1$ to $p$, so that all pairs of numbers appear in some row, is known as the covering design problem. In general, this is an open problem to solve exactly. The best known information about covering designs is kept at the La Jolla covering repository, maintained by Dan Gordon. Looking at the entry for $p=75$ and $n=6$ (link), we see that it is possible to solve your problem with a matrix that has $190$ rows. Furthermore, it is known that at least $188$ rows are necessary.

There are $\dbinom{75}2=2775$ pairs of numbers from 1 to 75. In each row $\dbinom62=15$ pairs can be formed. So we can get at most $15\cdot 50=750$ pairs from the table.
Clearly there is no way.
For $p$ possible numbers, $m$ rows and $n$ columns, we get that
$$\binom p2\le n\binom m2$$
as a necessary condition, which is equivalent to
$$p(p-1)\le nm(m-1)$$
Your 'naïve' approach seems a good one.
The rows that contain $1$ are ideally disjoint, save, of course, the element 1. So each such row should contain $n-1$ terms. Then there should be $(p-1)/(n-1)$ rows with '1'. Ideally, again, this quotient should be integer to avoid repeated pairs.
Now we discard 1 and count rows with 2. Also we avoid repeating pairs.  So we write 2 and numbers that are not both in the previous rows nor in the first row. This implies that we must choose a number $\neq 1$ from each row that had '1'. This discards $m-1$ rows in each step (the first one, and $m-2$ for the other numbers in the row).
Now, things get really complicated.
I'd suggest this algorithm:
INPUT: The set of $p\ge 2$ elements, the number $n\ge 1$ of rows and the number $m\ge p$ of columns.

Mark every element as 'non-wasted'. Set pairs to $p(p-1)/2$. Set rows to $n$.

Begin the row with a 'non-wasted' element k. Set every 'non-wasted' element different from k as 'non-discarded'.

For each full row, mark 'non-wasted' elements that are in this row as 'non-discarded'.

While the row is not full and there are 'non-discarded' elements left, append a 'non-discarded' element to the row. Mark this element as 'discarded'. Set pairs to pairs$-1$. End of while.

Add random elements to fill the row.

Set rows to rows$-1$

If there are no 'discarded' elements left, mark $k$ as 'wasted' and 'discarded'.

If pairs$=0$ the algorithm is succesfull and quit.

If rows$=0$ or there are $p$ 'wasted' elements it is impossible and quit.

Go to step 2.


OUTPUT: $0$ if it impossible or $1$ if it is not. A matrix $n\times m$ if it's possible, and also how many rows are useless.

Isn't ${6\choose 2} = 15$? Which.... makes the problem even more impossible, I suppose.

@fleablood Of course, thank you.
